# Building c++ project for Win XP in MSVC 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, windows-xp

I have a console application that I need to use on Windows XP. Also i'm using MSVC 2012 as an IDE. Problem, that when i run it on Win XP (SP3) i receive error message that this application is not a valid win32 application.

UPD:

After talking care about suggestions in the comments to this question, i've updated my question.

What does use my application:

- Urlmon.h/urlmon.lib
- boost::program_options
- c++11's regex

What i've already tryed:

- Build test application like "Hello, World!". It works on target Win XP
- Install Update 3 for MSVC 2012 & update 3 redist. to target machine
- Build app with static linking (/MT)

Dependency walker shows 3 messages:

- Missing WER.dll
- Missing IESHIMS.dll
- Unresolved C function "WNetRestoreConnectionA"

As far as i see nothing of listed in dependency walker should affect my app, but it still fail to load with error "not a valid win32 application".

Does anyone have ideas why>

Comment: Do you have the [c++ redistributable package](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679) on the win XP machine ?

Comment: So if you create a new c++ project, add a source file containing just `main`, build it with v110_xp it doesn't run on XP?

Comment: @msam good point, but then the OP would get a different error message (though it's of course possible he/she forgot to mention that)

Comment: @msam, yes, i have redistributable package on target XP machine.

Comment: not a valid win32 application...make sure you're compiling for 32bit (x86) not for 64bit...might also be an issue with WINVER

Comment: @msam, Target Machinne set to "MachineX86"

Comment: @stijn, simpe app like std::cout << "hello" works (wirh error about missing dll). So, what could cause difference why my app does not work at all?

Comment: urm, what missing dll?? As for the cause: well only you can figure out since you have the code.. Might be some dependency? Do you have a single project or multiple (eg an exe a and dlls)? If so, did you tarhet v110_xp in *all* of them? You could also open the exe on the target machine with Dependency Walker to get some clues

Comment: @stijn, dependency walker shows missing IESHIMS.DLL, WER.DLL in release build. If I make a debug build, it adds msvcp110d.dll, msvcr110d.dll.  Application still returns error "not a valid win32 app".

Comment: The debug build will not work on XP without VS2012 installed since the debug runtime is not redistributable.

Comment: @drescherjm, thanks for the tip. But my main app crashes even being build as release.

Comment: Did you build boost using the v110_xp toolset?

Comment: @drescherjm, yes. btw i've found a solution (posted below). Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The v110_xp toolset automatically specifies the SUBSYSTEM's MRV ("5.1" (WindowsXP)) but not the SUBSYSTEM

That was the problem. I've set SUBSYSTEM to "/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE" in project settings & problem with target Win XP dissapeared. Thanks everyone for comments.

Comment: Note to future self: I had some success using "/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE,5.1" where "/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE" failed

Answer (score 0):

As I know, MSVC 2012 toolset do not support windows XP. But you can use MSVC 2010 toolset in IDE 2012. Or use toolset v110_xp forom Visual Studio 2012 Update 1(I didn't try it).

This link may help

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2012/10/08/windows-xp-targeting-with-c-in-visual-studio-2012.aspx?Redirected=true

Comment: Already done when installed update 3 for msvc 2012. App still fail to load.